# Is there a way to check the priority in a priority queue in java?

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

I implemented various methods in a queue and then wanted to do the same for a priority queue, but is there a way to reach the attribute `priority`?
For example in the method `isInQueue`, this method should return true if the value and the priority received as argument are available is the priority queue.

```
public boolean isInQueue(int value) {
        PriorityQ q = new PriorityQ();
        
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return false;
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            if(this.queueFront() == value)
                return true;
            q.add(this.queueFront());
            this.remove();
            
        }
        
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            this.add(q.queueFront());
            q.remove();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is the whole class:

```
public class PriorityQ {
    
    class Element {
        int data; // ELEMENT'S DATA
        int priority; // ELEMENT’S PRIORITY
        Element next; // REFERENCE TO THE NEXT ELEMENT
        final static int DEFAULT_PRIORITY = 0;
        
        Element(int value, int priority) {
            this.data = value;
            this.priority = priority;
            this.next = this;
        }
        
        Element(int value) {
        this(value, DEFAULT_PRIORITY);
        }
        
    }
    
    
    private Element queue = null;
    
    
    public PriorityQ() {
        this.queue = null;
    }
    
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.queue == null;
    }
    
    
    public void remove() {
        if (this.isEmpty())
            System.exit(0);
        
        if (this.queue.next == this.queue)
            this.queue = null;
        else
            this.queue.next = this.queue.next.next;
    }
    
    public int queueFront() {
        if (this.isEmpty())
            System.exit(0);
        return this.queue.next.data;
    }
    
    
    public void add(int value, int priority) {
        Element tmp = new Element(value, priority);
        
        // special case 1: Empty queue
        if (this.isEmpty())
            this.queue = tmp;
        
        // Special case 2: insert a high priority element
        else if (tmp.priority > this.queue.priority) {
            tmp.next = this.queue.next;
            this.queue.next = tmp;
            this.queue = tmp;
        }
        
        // Special case 3: insert a low priority element
        else if (tmp.priority <= this.queue.next.priority) {
            tmp.next = this.queue.next;
            this.queue.next = tmp;
        }
        
        else { // insertion according to the priority
            Element cur = queue.next;
            
        while (cur.next.priority < tmp.priority)
            cur = cur.next;
        tmp.next = cur.next;
        cur.next = tmp;
        if (cur == this.queue)
            this.queue = this.queue.next;
        }
    }
    
    
    public void add(int value) {
        this.add(value, Element.DEFAULT_PRIORITY);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = " ";
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return"Empty list";
        
        Element cur = this.queue;
        s = " | " + cur.data +  " | ";
        cur = cur.next;
        while(cur != this.queue) {
            s+= cur.data + ", " + cur.priority + " | ";
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return s;
    }
    
    
    public int search(int value, int p) {
        PriorityQ q1 = new PriorityQ();
        int index = -1;
        int c = 0; //counter
        
        if(this.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("the queue is empty");
            return -1;
        }
        
        while(!this.isEmpty() && index == -1) {
            if(this.queueFront() == value)
                index = c;
            q1.add(this.queueFront(), p);
            this.remove();
            c++;
        }
        
        while(!q1.isEmpty()) {
            this.add(q1.queueFront(), p);
            q1.remove();
        }
        return index;
    }
    
    
    public boolean isInQueue(int value) {
        PriorityQ q = new PriorityQ();
        
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return false;
        
        while(!this.isEmpty()) {
            if(this.queueFront() == value)
                return true;
            q.add(this.queueFront());
            this.remove();
            
        }
        
        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            this.add(q.queueFront());
            q.remove();
        }
        return false;
    }
        
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQ q = new PriorityQ();
        
        q.add(1, 1);
        q.add(3, 4);
        q.add(3, 3);
        q.add(4, 1);
        q.add(5, 0);
        q.add(6, 8);
        System.out.println(q);
        
        System.out.println(q.search(1, 1));
        
        System.out.println(q.queueFront());
        
        System.out.println(q.isInQueue(3));
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you instantiate a new `PriorityQ` inside your methods?

Comment: Because I can only reach the top element of the queue which is ```queueFront```, so I unload all the elements from the queue into a new queue, then put them back.

Comment: That's because you're doing it wrong. The `isInQueue()` method should be a method of the `PriorityQ` class, so it can iterate the elements without modifying the queue. That also answers your question, because if you iterate the `Element` objects, you'd have access to the `priority` field.

Comment: @Andreas So you're saying that is it is possible to browse a priority queue? And if yes how? I won't have to remove all the elements from it to another temporary one?

Comment: To iterate the queues elements, a normal loop will work, but only for code inside the `PriorityQ` class: `for (Element curr = this.queue; curr != null; curr = curr.next) { /* use curr here */ }`

Comment: @Andreas but consider that I want to make a certain method, I iterate the queue the same way you mentioned in ur comment?